# Custom labels for DevExtreme Angular2 Form

Tags: angular, devextreme

I am using the latest version of [DevExtreme for Angular 2](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Form/Overview/Angular/Light/) as I'm writing this which is version 16.2.  I have a DevExtreme form which is getting data `user` from its component. As you can see, there isn't much to it.

```
<dx-form id="form" [(formData)]="user">
    <dxi-item dataField="fName"></dxi-item>
    <dxi-item dataField="lName"></dxi-item>
</dx-form>
```

I can't figure out, however, how to change a label from the default which is gathered from the `dataField`.  I've looked around in the documentation and I can't seem to find the answer.  I feel like I should be able to write:

```
<dxi-item dataField="lName" customLabel="Last Name"></dxi-item>
```

Seems like a feature that should exist and that should be easy to find in documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [label.text](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxForm/Item_Types/SimpleItem/label/#text) option is helpful in your case. The code should be like below:

```
<dxi-item dataField="lName" [label]="{text: 'Custom Label'}"></dxi-item>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sergey!  Yes, `[label]` can be used right in the `<dxi-item>` which is what I specifically asked for but, it turns out, one can also use `<dxo-label text="Custom Label"></dxo-label>`.